# How to make Vim's file browser open a file in a new buffer?

Tags: vim, file-browser

Sometimes I start Vim by pointing it at a directory, but I'm not certain yet which file I'll need to change, so I end up looking through several files.

Is there a way to make the file browser open a selected file into a new buffer so that the file browser is still available without having to reopen it with :e path/to/directory ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can have it open in a new buffer, but you can have it open in a new split using <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd> for a horizontal or vertical split respectively.

You could also preview the file using <kbd>p</kbd> which runs `:pedit <fname>` where `<fname>` is the file under the cursor.  This opens a new split window but doesn't change the cursor focus or position.  You can close this window with `:pclose` or simply `:pc`.

See `:help netrw-browse-maps` for more information.

Comment: 'O' doesn't open the file in new vertical browser instead 'v' does.

Comment: @Ramraj Hmm, I wonder if that has changed in the past 6 years or if I was wrong from the outset.  Either way I'll update this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: No prob. I'm new to using vim and was exploring vim tricks. I came across your answer for one of my doubts. :)

Answer (score 15):

This is not strictly speaking what you are asking for, but I think it's equivalent:

If you open a file from the file browser you can use CTRL-^ (and/or CTRL-6 ?) to return to the browser. This results in the file open in one buffer and the file browser open at the directory you started in.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Oh my god. Life changing.