# Returning to an initial buffer with a directory in Vim

Tags: vim

I first open a directory in Vim. Then I browse it and open a file. After I'm done with a file, I close it, whether by `:w` or `:bd` or `:q` -- doesn't matter, and I expect to come back the same buffer where I were initially -- the directory. But when I close the file, it also quits Vim. How can I just close that file and return to the initial buffer with the directory?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session)?

Comment: Isn't this really a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914969/how-to-make-vims-file-browser-open-a-file-in-a-new-buffer

Answer (score 1):

`:w` should be `:wq`.

Anyway, you don't need to "close" that buffer. Just go back to the file listing with `:b#`, or `<C-^>`, or `:Rex[plore]`.

If you absolutely *need* to "close" that buffer you can go back to the listing with `:b#` (`#` represents the previous buffer) and close that unwanted buffer with `:bd#`. In short:

```
:b#|bd#
```